# Powershell Get-EventLog (Intro)

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

Sorry I am just starting out writing a PowerShell scripts. I am trying to use a script to send a email once an event (error) comes across the Event Viewer. I do not want to use the feature that is incorporated in Event Viewer because it does not work on all Operating Systems. Here is what I have in my script now but I cannot import the Message or Data from the error that cut.

```
$event = Get-EventLog -LogName Application -Source "My Script-1" | where {$_.eventID -eq 1}

if ($event.EntryType -eq "Error")
{
    [string]$EmailBody = Event.Data
    $EmailFrom = "Test@google.com"
    $EmailTo = "lmill130@kent.edu"
    $EmailSubject = "This was sent from a PowerShell Script"
    $SMTPServer = "Example Server SMTP"
    Write-host "Sending Email Test"
    Send-MailMessage -From $EmailFrom -To $EmailTo -Subject $EmailSubject -Body $EmailBody -SmtpServer $SMTPServer
}
else 
{
    write-host "No error found"
    write-host "Here is the log entry that was inspected:"
    $event
}
```

If I put my own string in $EmailBody then it works with no issue but when I try to grab data from the Event I have no luck.

This is the script I use to create the test event.

```
#New-EventLog -LogName Application -Source "My Script-1" 
Write-EventLog -LogName Application -Source "My Script-1" -EntryType Error -
EventId 1 -Message "This is a test Entry."
```

I have a task created that when that event cuts then it runs the first script.

I have searched all over the internet and I have had no luck. Help please.

Comment: What does "I have no luck" mean? (When you say that something didn't work, you have to say _how_ it didn't work. Remember that nobody can see your screen.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats probaly because `Event.Data` doesn't return anything.

It has to be `$event.Data`, but I think you should maybe use `$event.Message` to get the info message of the error.

So all together would look like this:

```
$event = Get-EventLog -LogName Application -Source "My Script-1" | where {$_.eventID -eq 1}

if ($event.EntryType -eq "Error")
{
    [string]$EmailBody = $event.Data
    #or [string]$EmailBody = $event.Message

    $EmailFrom = "Test@google.com"
    $EmailTo = "lmill130@kent.edu"
    $EmailSubject = "This was sent from a PowerShell Script"
    $SMTPServer = "Example Server SMTP"
    Write-host "Sending Email Test"
    Send-MailMessage -From $EmailFrom -To $EmailTo -Subject $EmailSubject -Body $EmailBody -SmtpServer $SMTPServer
}
else 
{
    write-host "No error found"
    write-host "Here is the log entry that was inspected:"
    $event
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `[string]$EmailBody = Event.Data`

with `[string]$EmailBody = $Event.Data`

And its always better to use Message rather than data cause you are more bothered about the error message not the data which is going to be get captured.

Hope it helps.